# Is it possible to get PE or EPS for a STOCK using Interactive Broker API

Tags: interactive-brokers

I would like to get Price per Earnings or Earnings per Share for a stock symbol using Interactive Broker API. Is it possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get Reuters Fundamentals data via the API: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/reuters_fundamentals.html#report_type&gsc.tab=0

For each report type, you'll get back XML. The contents of the reports are not well documented, but several years of EPS history is available in the ReportsFinSummary report.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. do you know if this needs some kind of data subscription in my account?

Comment: I think it's free and may be turned on by default. If not it's cheap. Go to your research subscriptions in Account Management and look for Reuters fundamentals.  The calendar report requires a Wall Street Horizons subscription in Account Management, which is not free.